# How do I get the Unitary matrix of a circuit without using the 'unitary_simulator'?

Tags: programming, qiskit, quantum-state, unitarity

I am using jupyter notebook and qiskit. I have a simple quantum circuit and I want to know how to get the unitary matrix of the circuit without using 'get_unitary' from the Aer unitary_simulator. i.e.:By just using matrix manipulation, how do I get the unitary matrix of the circuit below by just using numpy and normal matrix properties?

[image: Circuit]

The result should equal this:

[[1.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j]

[0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 1.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j]

[0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 1.+0.j 0.+0.j]

[0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 1.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j]

[0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 1.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j]

[0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 1.+0.j]

[0.+0.j 0.+0.j 1.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j]

[0.+0.j 1.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j]]

## I tried doing the following but it did not result in the correct Unitary matrix

```
swapcnot = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0]])

layer1 = np.kron( swapcnot,np.eye(2) ) 

layer2 = np.kron( np.eye(2),swapcnot ) 

print( np.matmul(layer2,layer1) )
```

## The result:

[[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]

[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]

[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]

[0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]

[0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]

[0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]

[0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]

[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]]

Comment: See this question, which isn't technical but outlines the procedure you're looking for: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15651/how-to-read-the-unitary-matrix-of-a-quantum-circuit-in-projectq/15993#15993

Comment: @ryanhill1 Thank you. i tried this but could not get it to work unfortunately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first layer of your circuit, compute the tensor product between the unitary matrix of the (swapped) CNOT gate and the identity matrix (using numpy's kron()).
Do a similar operation for the second layer.
You will obtain two 8x8 matrices.
Then multiply them using numpy's matmul().

Here you have the working code:

```
import numpy as np

swapcnot = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0]])

layer1 = np.kron(np.eye(2),swapcnot )

layer2 = np.kron( swapcnot, np.eye(2) )

print( np.matmul(layer2,layer1) )
```

Output:

```
[[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
[0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this but as you can see in the edit of my question I get a 8*8 Identity matrix

Comment: The error in your code is that you do the same tensor product for both layers, but the layers are not equal. Try with layer2 = np.kron( np.eye(2),cnot ). Morever, you have to invert the order of the layers in matmul(), as you are looking for the matrix $U_2U_1$.

Comment: I just made these changes as seen in the above edit but I still do not get the correct result

Comment: Ok, you are using a cnot with the control and target that are exchanged, so you have to use the following matrix:

swapcnot = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0]])

Comment: Ok I tried it with the new swapcnot matrix but it still is not working for some reason

Comment: I added the full code. It works.

Comment: Can't thank you enough!!

Answer (score 5):

It seems you need the `Operator` class, from the `quantum_info` module:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit

circuit = QuantumCircuit(3)
circuit.cx(0, 1)
circuit.cx(1, 2)
circuit.draw('latex')
```

[image]

```
from qiskit.quantum_info import Operator
from qiskit.visualization.array import array_to_latex

array_to_latex(Operator(circuit))
```

$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
 \end{bmatrix}
$

Comment: Thank you for replying! Unfortunately I am trying to figure it out by not using any simulators, only algebra and normal matrix manipulation by using things such as tensor product

Answer (score 2):

Michele Amoretti's answer is essentially correct but there is a neater and less error-prone way to do it. There's no need to try to find the correct unitary matrix expressed with the correct qubit significance-ordering because the unitary matrices are all available in Qiskit's Gate classes as NumPy arrays. Taking them from here also saves you from manually typing the matrix out or copy-pasting it to have an explicit array in code (they can be printed anyway).

```
import numpy as np
import cmath
from qiskit.circuit.library import CXGate, IGate
from qiskit.aqua.utils import tensorproduct

cx_gate = CXGate().to_matrix()
id_gate = IGate().to_matrix()

layer1 = tensorproduct(id_gate, cx_gate)
layer2 = tensorproduct(cx_gate, id_gate)

qcirc_uni = np.matmul(layer2, layer1)
    
print(qcirc_uni.real)

array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Since this unitary matrix is real I used `cmath`'s `real` method to display it more clearly.

The reason that order of the matrices in your tensor products in your first computation is incorrect is because of the qubit significance-ordering convention used in Qiskit: [Why does Qiskit order its qubits the way it does? 1 Minute Qiskit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiqHj3_Avps&ab_channel=Qiskit). It's a really good idea to get on top of this.

Answer (score 1):

The following script does the work, but it is based on the **statevector_simulator**. I do not know if it is part of what you want to avoid using.

```
import qiskit
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, Aer
import numpy as np

#We need the statevector simulatro in this case
simulator = Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')

#Any circuit you want to analyse
qc = QuantumCircuit(3)
qc.cx(0,1)
qc.cx(1,2)

#Setting up unitary matrix
for reg in qc.qregs:
    nbits=len(reg)
H = np.zeros((2**nbits, 2**nbits), dtype=complex)

#Control quantum circuit
qc_test = QuantumCircuit(nbits)
#testing all initialize vector and filling up H
for i in range(2**nbits):
    init=list(range(2**nbits))
    for j in range(2 ** nbits):
        init[j]=0
    init[i]=1
    qc_test.initialize(init, range(nbits))
    qc_last = qc_test + qc
    result = qiskit.execute(qc_last, simulator).result()
    statevector = result.get_statevector()
    for j in range(2 ** nbits):
        H[j,i]=statevector[j]
#Printing desired output
print(H)
```

In your case the output is :

> [[1.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j]
> [0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 1.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j]
> [0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 1.+0.j 0.+0.j]
> [0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 1.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j]
> [0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 1.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j]
> [0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 1.+0.j]
> [0.+0.j 0.+0.j 1.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j]
> [0.+0.j 1.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j]]

If you really need to **avoid using any simulator** you can try using the following : (I have not coded the permutation part, which is the complex part I would say)

```
import qiskit
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, Aer
import numpy as np

#Any circuit you want to analyse
qc = QuantumCircuit(3)
qc.cx(1,0)
qc.cx(1,2)

for reg in qc.qregs:
    nbits=len(reg)
H = np.identity(2**nbits, dtype=complex)
Htmp = np.identity(2**nbits, dtype=complex)
#This part will loop through all operators and construct the corresponding matrix
for instr, qargs, cargs in qc._data:
    #This allows you to get the corresponding matrix of the local operator
    loc_mat = instr.to_matrix()
    comp = int(2**(np.log2(np.shape(H)[0]) - np.log2(np.shape(loc_mat)[0])))
    #construct a complementary identity operator to tensor product with the local operator
    Hkro=np.identity(comp, dtype=complex)
    Htmp = np.kron(Hkro, loc_mat)
    # should permut H first by rearranging the circuit by using the index of 
    # the used qregister, this part I did not have the courage to do 
    # (that's why people have coded it so well in unitary_simulator 
    # so why bother if you understand what is happening behind the scene)
    for j in range(len(qargs)):
        i_pos=qargs[j].index
        for k in range(len(qargs)):
            j_pos=qargs[k].index
    
    H=np.matmul(H, Htmp)
    #should back permut
    print(qargs)
print(H)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i really appreciate it! Unfortunately I am trying to figure it out by not using any simulators, only algebra and normal matrix manipulation by using things such as tensor product

Comment: Hi @Jared, I added a piece of code to help do the whole thing without any simulators. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, definitely helps!

Answer (score 1):

I found that if you multiply layer1 by layer2 (not layer2 @ layer1), the answer is consistent with the Qiskit one. So I tested through IBM experience and found that the state is reverse in Qiskit, which is a bit weird for me (that is if you apply a not gate to q0 in q0=0, q1=0, q2=0, a typical |000> state, it will become |001> but not |100>). Follow this idea you would find that the kronecker product in your first layer should be  $\ \mathbb{I}\ \otimes\ $SWAP-CNOT, exactly the reverse of your numpy computation. I'm also noob in Quantum Computing but it probably is the answer. (See Qiskit document https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-gates/multiple-qubits-entangled-states.html to get more sense on how it works)

Comment: Wow ok that makes a lot of sense now, was very confusing but that cleared it up. Thanks!